# How to find out the data which is positive number and having ' . ' in the data?

Tags: function, db2

I want to find the data which is having positive number . How many records have the positive values.
find out the ' . ' in the data 
We are using db2 database here.

Thanks,
katty.

Comment: What is the field type?

Comment: its amount field

Comment: There is no such a data type as `amount` in db2. Refer to the [Data types](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008483.html) link. Can you provide some sample data in such a field, an example of your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: Column name is 'amount'  and its VARCHAR. If one record has 1000.78 and another has -1000.78, i should find out only 1000.78 value and required to to only on decimal point(.) not  more than one.on top of this i need to test if record has any space between data ex: 1000 896 should also goes to failure record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
 SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN > 0
```

and

```
 SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN LIKE '%.%'
```